Is there a way to set the last run of a query as a date parameter?
I use SQL at work specifically I use it through a website called SLATE by Technolutions, and I'm trying to set a query up that pulls records but only since the last time its been run, there's a setting that enables this however it won't pull the a record if its been pulled in a query before.
I'm trying to set the start date of the query as the date of the last run of the query. what i have now is a simple 1 day pull. Is there any key word for this as I'm using today to pull any records this way. If not what would I put into this SQL to get this result?
/* Material Received (with Date) */
(a.[id] IN (select a.[id] 
            from [material] m 
            inner join [application] a on (a.[person] = m.[record]) 
            where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
              and (m.[record] is not null) 
              and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 

            union all 

            select [record] 
            from [material] 
            where ([key] in ('app')) 
              and ([record] is not null) 
              and (convert(date, [updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 

            union all 

            select a.[id] 
            from [material] m 
            inner join [school] s on (s.[id] = m.[record]) 
            inner join [application] a on (a.[person] = s.[record]) 
            where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
              and (m.[record] is not null) 
              and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 

            union all 

            select a.[id] 
            from [material] m 
            inner join [application.reference] ar on (ar.[id] = m.[record]) 
            inner join [application] a on (a.[id] = ar.[application]) 
            where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
              and (m.[record] is not null) 
              and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 

            union all 

            select a.[id] 
            from [material] m 
            inner join [school.report] sr on (sr.[id] = m.[record]) 
            inner join [application] a on (a.[id] = sr.[application]) 
            where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
              and (m.[record] is not null) 
              and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate()))
           )
)

I've tried a few keywords like run or last run. I'm not very experienced in SQL so I'm not sure what language I should use

What RDBMS are you using? You might be able to do this by abusing the QueryStore - but generallyt speaking, a SELECT-type query can't be used to update state (i.e. write anything) - but you could use a multi-statement batch that has an INSERT INTO myLogTable - also, if you're after rows-changed-or-added-since-I-last-checked then a better approach is to use CT/CDC ("Change Tracking/Change Data Capture" - if your RDBMS supports it).

You need a mechanism not a keyword, I think.
You are selecting mainly from material table.
You could add 2 columns into material table.

Name : Pulled (or Selected), data type: bit or tiny int.

Name : Pulled Date (or Selected Date), data type: Datetime We store both date and time by using Getdate() Sql Server or Now()  - Mysql-Postgre function.
     /* Material Received (with Date) */
     (a.[id] IN (select a.[id] 
     from [material] m 
     inner join [application] a on (a.[person] = m.[record]) 
     where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
       and (m.[record] is not null) and m.pulled!=1
       and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1,      
     convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 


     union all 

     select [record] 
     from [material] 
     where ([key] in ('app')) 
       and ([record] is not null) and pulled!=1
       and (convert(date, [updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, 
     convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 

     union all 

     select a.[id] 
     from [material] m 
     inner join [school] s on (s.[id] = m.[record]) 
     inner join [application] a on (a.[person] = s.[record]) 
     where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
       and (m.[record] is not null) and m.pulled!=1
       and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, 
     convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 

     union all 

     select a.[id] 
     from [material] m 
     inner join [application.reference] ar on (ar.[id] = m.[record]) 
     inner join [application] a on (a.[id] = ar.[application]) 
     where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
       and (m.[record] is not null) and m.pulled!=1
       and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, 
     convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 

     union all 

     select a.[id] 
     from [material] m 
     inner join [school.report] sr on (sr.[id] = m.[record]) 
     inner join [application] a on (a.[id] = sr.[application]) 
     where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
       and (m.[record] is not null) and m.pulled!=1
       and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, 
     convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate()))
    ))



--Add this part in the same query but after your select statements.
Update m
    Set Pulled=1,
       [Pulled Date]=Getdate()   --use now() function for mysql-postgre
    from [material] m 
         inner join [application] a on (a.[person] = m.[record]) 
    where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
          and (m.[record] is not null) and m.pulled!=1
          and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1,convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate()))

Update m
    Set Pulled=1,
        Pulled Date]=Getdate()
    from [material] m
    where ([key] in ('app')) and ([record] is not null) and pulled!=1
          and (convert(date, [updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 
    
Update m
   Set Pulled=1,
      [Pulled Date]=Getdate()
   from [material] m 
      inner join [school] s on (s.[id] = m.[record]) 
      inner join [application] a on (a.[person] = s.[record]) 
   where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
         and (m.[record] is not null) and m.pulled!=1
         and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 
    
Update m
    Set Pulled=1,
        [Pulled Date]=Getdate()
    from [material] m 
        inner join [application.reference] ar on (ar.[id] = m.[record]) 
        inner join [application] a on (a.[id] = ar.[application]) 
    where (m.[key] in ('app')) and (m.[record] is not null) and m.pulled!=1
         and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 
    
Update m
    Set Pulled=1,
        [Pulled Date]=Getdate()
    from [material] m 
        inner join [school.report] sr on (sr.[id] = m.[record]) 
        inner join [application] a on (a.[id] = sr.[application]) 
    where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
        and (m.[record] is not null) and m.pulled!=1
        and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate()))

When you need to select records that is already selected you can modify your select query by adding Pulled Date into where clause.
Alternatively, you can write update part into a scalar valued Function and select its result.
Like
select a.[id], dbo.sf_update_pulleddate(parameters) 
            from [material] m 
            inner join [application] a on (a.[person] = m.[record]) 
            where (m.[key] in ('app')) 
              and (m.[record] is not null) and .mpulled!=1
              and (convert(date, m.[updated]) between dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and convert(date, getdate())) 

